# hibernate5 assign duplicate ids to the objects

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-5.x

I'm upgrading Hibernate4 to Hibernate5. Spring-4.3.7 And facing the problem that hibernate assigns duplicate IDs to the objects while EntityManager.persist(object) that results in exception :-

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was
 already associated with the session : [com.domain.multilanguage.LiteralText#498]; nested exception
is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.domain.multilanguage.LiteralText#498][machine=]
```

I debug inside the SharedEntityManagerCreator and found that, hibernate only assigns 0 - 49 objects total 50 ids and after that it start duplicating the ids.

I'm using the sequence generator GenerationType.SEQUENCE.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "idGenerator", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 50)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public long getId() {
        return mId;
    }
```

This is working fine with Hibernate4. What could be the problem here, please.

Comment: Checkout comments and links there: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10983

Comment: Thank you @Popandopolos, it worked. :-) i added property "<prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>" to hibernate jpaProperties, now it's using old SequenceHiLoGenerator, that actually working in my case.